# Applying of projections and monadic functions in k

Tags: kdb, k

How to properly apply a monadic functions and projections in k?

```
KDB+ 3.6 2018.05.17 Copyright (C) 1993-2018 Kx Systems
q) \
  (5*;10*)@\:2
10 20
  ({x};{x*x})@\:2
2 4
  (#;#)@\:2
(#[2];#[2])
```

Why 2 first examples work properly and the last one doesn't? I thought it would be:

```
  (#;#)@\:2
1 1
```

but it gives me a strange result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

# ([take](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/take/)) is a diadic function, unlike count which is monadic. This is why you were getting a projection when applying only a single argument to it.

```
q)count
#:
q)type (count)
101h
q)type (#)
102h
```

You can use the . ([dot-apply](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/apply/#apply-index)) operator on diadic functions with two operands to return a result that is not a projection.

```
(#;#) .\: (3;til 10)
0 1 2
0 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

```
q)\
  (#;#)@\:2
(#[2];#[2])
  (#:;#:)@\:2
1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

For the purpose of completeness, this relates to unary forms which is documented here: https://code.kx.com/q/basics/exposed-infrastructure/#unary-forms